# MySQL in PHP; Edit column value before comparing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, pdo

I have a MySQL query in my PHP code like this:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT name FROM persons WHERE name = :name');
$statement->execute(array(':name' => "Peter-Loew"));
```

What I want to to is to edit `:name` before comparing with `"Peter-Loew"`.

I want to run a PHP code like this on `:name` before comparing with `"Peter-Loew"`:

```
<?php
function url_replace($url_replace) {
$url_replace = str_ireplace(array('Ä','Ö','Ü'), array('Ae','Oe','Ue'), $url_replace);
$url_replace = preg_replace('~[^a-zA-Z0-9]+~', '-', $url_replace);
$url_replace = trim($url_replace, '-');
$url_replace = rtrim($url_replace, '-');
return $url_replace;
}
?>
```

How can I do this? Or, does anybody know how to call this what I'm looking for? Any hint?

Comment: You want to run your name through `url_replace` before doing your `SELECT`?

Comment: @Machavity Yes, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to clean your database independently first. So when you do your `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, you'll run `url_replace` on the `name` field. Then, when you run your check like in the question, you can run `url_replace` on the value you're checking against.

In other words, you need to make the data in the table go in uniformly so it comes out uniformly.

Comment: Oh, you want to run the PHP function ON the database

Comment: I've updated my answer. There's no way to run a PHP function against an entire table on a per-query basis like you're suggesting. You'll need to wash the table through your function separately, row by row, and update it that way.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer but this isn't what I'm looking for. Updating all rows wouldn't be a problem, (done in few minutes by hand). But this isn't what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do what you want, but it is **highly not recommended**, otherwise you will have serious performance issues with this approach.

The best approach to this is sanitizing the name before saving it to DB.

If you really need to do this, than you should use the [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function chained a lot of times and then use the [TRIM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function...

Example Query:

`SELECT name FROM persons WHERE TRIM(REPLACE(name, 'Ä', 'Ae')) = :name;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll have a look at it.